# HashMap for enum as key

Tags: java

I had posted somewhat similar question before also. I got clarification for my doubts as well. But still I need something more. The Hashmap will be initialized with the enum object as the key and a threadpool instance as the value. I am confused as of how to initialize the HashMap for every object been called by some other process ..To make clear :
My program, MyThreadpoolExcecutorPgm.java initializes a HashMap
My Progran AdditionHandler.java requests a thread from the HashMap by passing ThreadpoolName (enum). I am getting "No thread available from HashMap" message. Please do help me.
Below given is my code:

```
 public class MyThreadpoolExcecutorPgm {

    enum ThreadpoolName {
        DR, BR, SV, MISCELLENEOUS;
    }

    private static String threadName;
    private static HashMap<ThreadpoolName, ThreadPoolExecutor>
        threadpoolExecutorHash;

    public MyThreadpoolExcecutorPgm(String p_threadName) {
        threadName = p_threadName;
    }

    public static void fillthreadpoolExecutorHash() {
        int poolsize = 3;
        int maxpoolsize = 3;
        long keepAliveTime = 10;
        ThreadPoolExecutor tp = null;
        threadpoolExecutorHash = new HashMap<ThreadpoolName, ThreadPoolExecutor>();
        for (ThreadpoolName poolName : ThreadpoolName.) // failing to implement
        {
            tp = new ThreadPoolExecutor(poolsize, maxpoolsize, keepAliveTime,
                    TimeUnit.SECONDS, new ArrayBlockingQueue<Runnable>(5));
            threadpoolExecutorHash.put(poolName, tp);
        }
    }

    public static ThreadPoolExecutor getThreadpoolExcecutor(
            ThreadpoolName poolName) {
        ThreadPoolExecutor thread = null;
        if (threadpoolExecutorHash != null && poolName != null) {
            thread = threadpoolExecutorHash.get(poolName);
        } else {
            System.out.println("No thread available from HashMap");
        }
        return thread;
    }
}
```

AdditionHandler.java

```
public class AdditionHandler{

    public void handle() {
        AddProcess setObj = new AddProcess(5, 20);
        ThreadPoolExecutor tpe = null;
        ThreadpoolName poolName =ThreadpoolName.DR; //i am using my enum    
        tpe = MyThreadpoolExcecutorPgm.getThreadpoolExcecutor(poolName);
        tpe.execute(setObj);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AdditionHandler obj = new AdditionHandler();
        obj.handle();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect you're just looking for the static `values()` method which is added to every enum:

```
for (ThreadpoolName poolName : ThreadpoolName.getValues())
```

Alternatively, you can use `EnumSet.allOf()`:

```
for (ThreadpoolName poolName : EnumSet.allOf(ThreadpoolName.class))
```

(As Bozho says, [`EnumMap`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/EnumMap.html) is a good alternative here. You still need to loop through the enum values.)

Comment: Thanks a lot friends....But still i am getting same "No thread available from HashMap" ...also a NullPointer Exception.Any way to check how the HashMap is getting filled up..?

Comment: @vidhya: Please post a short but *complete* program which demonstrates the problem. Presumably you're getting the NullPointerException because you're returning a null reference from getThreadpoolExcecutor. As for why you're seeing "No thread available from HashMap" - the message is misleading, because all it means is that ei9ther threadpoolExecutorHash is null, or poolName is null. Find out which.

Comment: Thanks Jon ...for ur directions ...because i added the following and now my program is excecuting without errors...static {
 fillthreadpoolExecutorHash();
 }

Answer (score 5):

First, you'd better use [`EnumMap`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/EnumMap.html). Then make sure you have filled the map before you invoked the method.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate through enum values by one of (in descending order of preference)

```
for(Enum value : Enum.values())

for(Enum value : EnumSet.allOf(Enum.class))

for(Enum value : Enum.class.getEnumConstants())
```

But you should also be using an `EnumMap`.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "descending order of preference" ?

Comment: Of the three options, I would prefer the first the most, and the last the least.

Comment: I got this - the why is the matter - do not answer me here you can just edit the answer

Comment: It's the shortest and clearest. It was a while ago, but I assume I was just giving a more complete list to get a `Collection<? extends Enum>`. The latter ones would be useful if you were using reflection.